# Center element with flex bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Though I hate css I have to work with it

I am trying to center an element with flex, which is advertised as the easy solution. Reality is that it doesn't work.

What I am doing wrong? I want the image logo centered exactly in the middle of the page in width and height, exactly in the middle.

Guides says you have to justify and align center.

This is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxGdQN?page=1&)

Another simplified codepen: [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvebQy)
Code:

HTML

```
<div class="maindiv d-flex">
    <div class="mainlogo justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <img id="fadinglogo" class="mainlogo justify-content-center align-items-center" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/The_Venus_Project_logo_image.png/600px-The_Venus_Project_logo_image.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*DEFAULT MVC PROJECT CSS*/
html body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; }

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
  white-space: normal; }

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
  max-width: 280px; }

/*BEGINNING CUSTOM SASS*/
.maindiv * {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }

#fadinglogo {
  width: auto; }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think this is why, you have one div inside the flexbox with width: 100%, so technically it is centered. So if you remove width:100% from .mainlogo and add justify-content: center to .maindiv it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you are doing wrong. Display flex and its flex properties should be applied to same parent but instead you have applied flex to "mainDiv" and its properties to "mainlogo" div.

Here is the fix.

```
.maindiv{//display:flex;}
.mainlogo{display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;}
```

Changed the height values to exactly center it in code pen.

https://codepen.io/Harsh89/pen/RYeWvX

Comment: Or just add `d-flex` to the `.mainlogo` container

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score -1):

Just give below css to image,

```
img.fadinglogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

It will center align vertically and horizontally as well...

Answer (score -1):

Try writing CSS with your calm mind, you forgot to add "Bootstrap" CSS in your both `codepen`. try this one. It's pretty simple and useful

https://codepen.io/Dilip7597/pen/VGEeKZ

Comment: I don't know about that, but I checked in both of the codepens and the only reason your code wasn't working is because the bootstrap css was not linked. I did linked it through setting -> css and then your code also worked like charm.

Comment: I don't know but that was the only problem with your code, missing of the bootstrap css file.